# Proposal: enable the Clippy chat easter egg on Sharepoint chat board

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Simple idea.. title says all.
As some of you may already know, there is an easter egg found on some specific chat boards that will display a Clippy stile animation when someone post a message in the form "How do I ....." (actual regex is a little more complex).

As somebody may already have notice, I like easter eggs... so I was wondering.

Clippy == Office == SharePoint

**Why** the egg is not available on our chat boards? Can some of the mods request the egg to be enabled in the land where Office live, aka SharePoint exchange? Would people like this or do they prefer to never see the UnHelper Clippy again?

EDIT: to be clearer, I am talking about this:

[image]

Comment: What does the animation do? And would it deter users from asking questions?

Comment: The animation only works while in a chat room, so no, it won't deter people. Only thing it does it display a popup similar to the old office "You need help?" Clippy prompt whenever somebody post a question that stars with words like "How do I/ How can I/How to make" etc

Comment: @rjcup3 - added a screenshot.

Comment: If anything it would probably help to deter people from asking questions in chat. This has my support.

Comment: Consider that clicking the "Yes please" button will launch a search... So maybe it will deter people asking question already answered too :P

Comment: Is this dead in the water?

Comment: @rjcup3 so it seems. That said, SharePoint meta site is famous for resembling the gray sea....

Comment: I'm sorry but that reference is lost on me as I'm from across the pond. What do you mean by resembling the gray sea?

Comment: @rjcup3 yea, it was pretty nerd of me. The gray sea is a place that appears in about two episodes of an old anime (and all fans hoped it would have a meaning... but no, too dark for the target audience it seems). It is a world all painted in gray, with an endless sea with no waves and no life at all. Only a demon lurking under it. Some say it is a Cthulhu reference... anyway it comed to mind as the perfect essence of a dead board. ^_^

Comment: When I Googled it the only thing that comes up is gray sea salt from France. Thought it was a Euro thing.

Comment: @rjcup3 - it seems that the original name used in the US/English states is "Dark Ocean" (seems that Dead Ocean is also used, along with Dark Endless Ocean). I was traslating the name that they miss-translated to my mother language.... urgh.

Comment: What's your mother language?

Comment: @rjcup3 Let's just say that MI is also a city in my country. Anyway, with the above info you have all clue to understand what anime I was talking about